# Deleting files from Remote FTP-Server older than X days (only ftp, curl or lftp)

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I have similar situation descibed here: [Deleting files from Remote FTP-Server older than x days](https://serverfault.com/questions/101920/deleting-files-from-remote-ftp-server-older-than-x-days/763431#763431)
and I see this is not answered fully yet so I would like to register the new one.

My files are having a names containing date and time when they had been generated:
    xxx.yyy.z.aaa_01_20160313102903_DUMP01.dmp
and are uploaded to remote FTP server.
Position of the date and time (e.g. 20160313102903) in the file name is static. Of course time stamps of those files are also valid.

My goal is to delete files older than X days using a script which should run in cron on a linux machine where I can use only curl or lftp.

- I can't use any other protocol except ftp to access FTP server (no sftp, no ssh)
- I can't use date command with "X days ago" syntax as that linux machine is running BusyBox v1.20.2 which doesn't understand human date references
- I can't create a temporary subfolders at that FTP server

I have been searching scripts which should lead me to the solution but because I'm linux noob I'm progressing very slowly and so far I have found only:

- I'm able to list the date of X days ago: date -d "@$(($(date +%s) - 86400 * $XDays))"
- I'm able to list all the files from FTP server: curl ftp://[FTP_IP]/folder/subfolder/* --user MyUser@[FTP_IP]:[MyUserPassword] --list-only"

Real script, instead of obvious steps describing what that script should do, like:

- Get the list of files using the --list-only option of curl
- Parse the list for the files you want to delete
- Use the --quote or --request option to send a rm or DELE command with the selected filenames

is very welcome.

Comment: We're not a script writing service. If you write a script and get stuck ask about that though [so] may be a better place for that.

Comment: I have placed a new question based on the 'Castaglia' advise. Solution provided in answers on similar questions are those which using: 1) sftp protocol or 2) date command with "X days ago" syntax or 3) temporary subfolder creation durectly on FTP server. As I explained I can't use any of them. I stuck at converting a string $line="20130312161706" into $line="2013-03-12 12:16:06" as this is required to use a command: DateLine=$(date -d "$(echo "$line" | cut -d'_' -f3-3)" +%s);